# VS 2022 x64 MSBuild trying to load the x86 binary

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2022

VS 2022 x64 MSBuild trying to load the x86 binary:

I have an MSBuild extension (target file) which loads my task extension DLL, and it was building perfectly with the x86 MSBuild.
So, in order to build with VS 2022 x64 MSBuild I have rebuilt my task DLL with x64 configuration and then modified the MSBuild extension (target file) to use the x64 task DLL with x64 MSBuild.

However, the x64 MSBuild always trying to load the x86 task DLL and ends the build with the error "task could not be loaded from the assembly". Why the x64 MSBuild is trying to load the x86 task DLL.

Task DLL is built in C++ CLI/CLR, I have configured the MSBuild extension to load the task DLL based on the architecture, as specified in the below article:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TaskTLibrary"
       AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)ArchSpecificTasks.dll"
       Architecture="x86" />
<UsingTask TaskName="TaskLibrary"
       AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)ArchSpecificTasks.dll"
       Architecture="x64" />
```

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/msbuild-and-64-bit-visual-studio-2022/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-4025064

Can you please help me why the x86 task DLL is getting loaded with the x64 MSBuild, how can I restrict the x64 MSBuild to load only the x64 task DLL and the x86 MSBuild to load the x86 task DLL.

Thanks..

Comment: The task names in the snipped you provided don't match. What did you actually use for your case?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn : Actually I want to load the x64 DLL when I use x64 MSBuild and load x86 DLL when I use x86 MSBuild commands. Actually, I want to execute some action after the post build, so I have added the target in all my projects. 
So, when I build the project with x64 MSBuild, it ends with Invalid binary format error.

So, is there anyway I can restrict and execute the x86 task during the x86 MSBuild, and execute x64 task during the x64 MSBuild. ?